# How to make a smooth animation from the center of the screen to the top left corner of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I want to animate an image to move from the center of the screen to the top left corner smoothly

I tried with transitions but it's not working as intended.

```js
const acoustic = document.querySelector('.acoustic');
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => acoustic.classList.toggle('selected'));
```

```css
.acoustic {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90vw;
}

.acoustic .guitar{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s forwards;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: red;
}

.acoustic.selected .guitar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere</p>
<div class="acoustic"><div class="guitar"></div></div>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding your HTML code and embedding it into a snippet?

Comment: [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) please.

Comment: The project is made with react, i don't have the patience to translate to html css and js. I can give you the github repo: [https://github.com/Lawrencium04/site-atestat]

Comment: Can you describe what "not working as intended" means? I have a guess, but maybe it would be better to have that information there.

Comment: The problem is that i's not smooth. it's going towards the bottom right corner first then goes back to the top left corner with a weird shaky movement. (I changed the acoustic.css files a bit to replicate the original problem).

Comment: [Check this bin](https://jsbin.com/zetocayesi/1/edit?html,css,output) - click anywhere other than the box to see the animation. But, you describe what sounds like CSS styles overriding/colliding during the animation sequence. Can't help with that without the html and CSS.

Comment: @RandyCasburn you should make an answer with that, seems to be working as the described expectation. I would add that the animation-timing-function may affect how smooth it feels like as well. More information on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: @VelizarStavrev - nah - OP states "_i don't have the patience to translate to html css and js..._". So...meh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jank comes from the fact that you specify `right` in the first state, then `left` in the second state. Since you're not changing the same property you don't get a smooth transition.

Change `right: -50%;` to `left: 50%`.

```js
const acoustic = document.querySelector('.acoustic');
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => acoustic.classList.toggle('selected'));
```

```css
.acoustic {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90vw;
}

.acoustic .guitar{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s forwards;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: red;
}

.acoustic.selected .guitar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere</p>
<div class="acoustic"><div class="guitar"></div></div>
```